# Complex Analysis with differential forms

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, differential-forms, big-list, de-rham-cohomology

I'm studying a little of Complex Analysis and I have seen that I can use the integrals of complex functions as integrals of differential forms in $\mathbb{R}^n.$
For example: Cauchy Theorem for complex analytic functions is a consequence of the fact that a closed differential form on a simply connected set is exact.

My question is :
Are there other famous theorem of Complex Analysis that I can prove with the theory of differential forms in Euclidean space?

Answer (score 0):

One such book is H. Cartan, Elementary theory of analytic functions of one or several complex variables, Paris, Herman, 1963.